# how to get dns server ip in iphone

Tags: iphone, dns

I have tried to fetch /etc/resolv.conf by
open("/etc/resolv.conf", 0644)

but it return -1 and the errno is 2 which means "no such file"

what can I do?

Comment: I would have guessed that there was no such file on your system. But then I don't know how accurate Apple error messages are. I know for a fact that Microsoft error codes are usually completely unrelated to the actual error encountered.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999612/iphone-get-3g-dns-host-name-and-ip-address

Answer (score 3):

You can't access files outside your Application's sandbox.

Comment: We have a winner! Apple is lying to you! The file exists but you don't have access! What is worse than no error message? A dishonest error message!

Comment: @PP Sure, Apples engineers have explicitly added this "wrong" error code for this particular device OS.

Comment: There's no indication that the message is dishonest or even wrong. It might just be omitting some salient information. "There is no such file" is what the error says, but the non-truncated message could actually be "There is no such file available to you".

Comment: are there any solution to get dns server ip on iphone app?