# Getting DNS server IP on IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get the my dns server IP using using `libresolv` framework , but all I get is "0.0.0.0"

```
-(void) getDns
{
    res_init();

    for (int i=0;i<MAXNS;i++)
    {       
        printf("%s",inet_ntoa(_res.nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr));

    }
}
```

Anything wrong with my code here ?

Thanks

**Edit**

Tried to use the code in SO's other question, but this is what I get when the host is "apple.com"

```
2011-03-16 15:07:21.689 MobileMax[5876:207] RESOLVED 0:<17.149.160.49>
2011-03-16 15:07:21.691 MobileMax[5876:207] RESOLVED 1:<17.251.200.70>
2011-03-16 15:07:21.691 MobileMax[5876:207] RESOLVED 2:<17.112.152.57>
```

While when running the command : `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
I get `nameserver 10.0.0.138` which is what I want.

Any idea how to get that ?

**Edit2**

I tried this as well, but still getting the "0.0.0.0" response.

```
u_char buf[NS_PACKETSZ];
int responseLen;             

    res_query("www.google.com",ns_c_in,ns_t_ns,buf,sizeof(buf));
```

Comment: Oh now I get what you want... only way I can see right now is to actually parse `/etc/resolv.conf`. I'm curious, why do you need the IP of your DNS server ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999612/iphone-get-3g-dns-host-name-and-ip-address

Comment: I also get the 0.0.0.0 information when running the simulator. But when I try the code on a real device it actually returns the right dns ip-address. So there is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You are not resolving anything, you are just printing the address stored in some variable. You actually need to call `res_query` or `res_search`. But on iOS, you're better off with using the CFHost* methods, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000441/how-to-perform-dns-query-on-ios). There's also [sample code from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CFHostSample/Listings/CFHostSample_c.html) (search the `MyResolveNameToAddress` function).</strike>

Update after understanding the question: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972805/how-to-get-dns-server-ip-in-iphone) you cannot access the `/etc/resolv.conf` file (permissions). But according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260518/finding-dns-server-settings-programmatically-on-mac-os-x) you *might* succeed by using the SystemConfigFramework but I've got no idea whether it works on iOS (the framework exists, but whether that information is exposed I don't know).

Comment: Well, I guess there is some way, hopefully someone will answer me someday :)

Answer (score 0):

> Try below code to get DNS Server Address . Don't forget to link libresolv.lib

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <ifaddrs.h>
    #include <resolv.h>
    #include <dns.h>

    - (NSString *) getDNSServers
    {
    // dont forget to link libresolv.lib
    NSMutableString *addresses = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"DNS Addresses \n"];

    res_state res = malloc(sizeof(struct __res_state));

    int result = res_ninit(res);

    if ( result == 0 )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < res->nscount; i++ )
        {
            NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String :  inet_ntoa(res->nsaddr_list[i].sin_addr)];
            [addresses appendFormat:@"%@\n",s];
            NSLog(@"%@",s);
        }
    }
    else
        [addresses appendString:@" res_init result != 0"];

    return addresses;
}
```

Comment: This will fail to detect IPv6 DNS servers (and will actually break if you have some).  I have some Swift 3 code in my answer for another question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41303040/6782

Comment: either way, you shouldn't be peeking into the internals of `res->nsaddr_list` - the `res_getservers()` function returns the list

Comment: Objective-C approach:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256024/get-dns-server-ip-from-iphone-settings/43344910#43344910

inet_ntoa is not a best approach since it is supporting only IPv4