# Get DNS server IP address and Search Domain from iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swing

How can I get the **DNS** server IP address and the **Search Domain** from the WiFi connection shown in the picture below in objective-c or swift.

[image: WiFi Connection information]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting DNS server IP on IPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325401/getting-dns-server-ip-on-iphone)

Comment: Did you even read that post? I have read it before and it does not provide a answer to my question, it does not speak about search domains.

Comment: Yes I did. The solution linked at the very least gets the IP address, and if you look through `resolv.h` which is mentioned in the link, there is a possibility of getting what you're looking for via the `dnsrch` variable