# Default DNS server in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, dns

I'm wondering how do I get default DNS server in monotouch?

this code works perfectly in simulator, but gives 0 records on device.

```
NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (IPAddress ipAddr in ipProps.DnsAddresses)
   Console.WriteLine(ipAddr);
```

from the other hand, this code works on both simulator and device:

```
IPHostEntry he = Dns.GetHostEntry(domain);
dns = he.HostName.ToString();
```

having all this, I assume DNS server address is stored somewhere. I mean it is accessible. How to get its IP?

Comment: The first code snippet won't compile. I assume you're using something similar to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dnsaddresses.aspx ?

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972805/how-to-get-dns-server-ip-in-iphone) the SDK does not make this information available.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972805/how-to-get-dns-server-ip-in-iphone

Comment: i'm not trying to get access to resolv.conf. I need to get current DNS server IP. I'm pretty sure I've seen this kind of examples made in C/Obj-C

Comment: They are trying to do the same thing you are, and the lack of alternate suggestions leads me to believe the SDK does not provide access to this info.

Comment: Have you read that one? Dunno, maybe it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000441/how-to-perform-dns-query-on-ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get the IP Address in MonoTouch:-

```
    public string GetIPAddress()
    {
        string address = "Not Connected";
        try
        {
            #if SIM
                address = IPAddress.FileStyleUriParser("127.0.0.1"); 
            #else
                string str = Dns.GetHostName() + ".local";
                IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(str);
                address = (
                           from addr in hostEntry.AddressList
                           where addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork
                           select addr.ToString()
                           ).FirstOrDefault();
            #endif
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Add error handling....
        }
        return address;
    }
```

Note the difference between using the simulator and device.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe such an API exists on iOS (but I would be happy to be proven wrong). Other projects, that needs this information, relies on [hacks](https://github.com/fopina/transmission-ios/commit/d7eed6c38010489e1e680c473092e75591f7e863) like using well known, static address to DNS servers) to overcome this.

Now the reason code like this:

```
        var all = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces ();
        foreach (NetworkInterface ni in all) {
            var props = ni.GetIPProperties ();
            foreach (var dns in props.DnsAddresses) {
                Console.WriteLine (dns);
            }
        }
```

works *on the simulator* is because it's a simulator and **not** an emulator. IOW the host (Mac) computer allows far more things than a *real* iOS device will allow.

More precisely `props` will be an instance of `System.Net.NetworkInformation.MacOsIPInterfaceProperties`, which inherits from `UnixIPInterfaceProperties`, and [ends up reading](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/IPInterfaceProperties.cs#L122) the `/etc/resolv.conf` file (which iOS disallow your application from reading).

The second case, calling `Dns.GetHostEntry`, goes down into the [Mono runtime](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/metadata/socket-io.c#L3097) but end up calling `gethostname` which does not require the caller to know the DNS server address.