# Get DNS Server IP Address in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin

I have the need to do my own DNS queries.  However there does not appear to be a way to get the DNS servers address from the device.

IPAddressCollection dnsAddresses = ipProperties.DnsAddresses;

This always returns 0 DNS servers but yet it works fine in the simulator.   Is there any kind of workaround to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Can you directly query Google's DNS servers?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999612/iphone-get-3g-dns-host-name-and-ip-address Porting that to monotouch is non-obvious, and would require P/Invoking libresolv and mapping the __res_state struct.

Comment: I could, use Google DNS, but thats dirty.  Not always available from say a private network and will not contain custom DNS entries.  I cant not believe this is not possible on iOS.